# Running Flask-SocketIO app on PythonAnywhere raises IOError

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere, flask-socketio

I'm trying to run a chat app using Flask-SocketIO on PythonAnywhere.  Loading the page takes a long time or only partially loads and the chat doesn't work.  It works when I run it locally.  Why doesn't it work on PythonAnywhere?

```
2016-10-27 13:23:27,059 :IOError: write error
2016-10-27 13:23:27,060 :Error running WSGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 156, in __call__
    yield response
GeneratorExit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PythonAnywhere [doesn't support websockets](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1748/). Flask-SocketIO requires WebSocket support from the server, so it won't work if that's not available.

Comment: Oh darn! Do you know an alternative free Webhosting service where I can deploy my Flask Webapp with a websocket?

Comment: It's not free, but I really would suggest Digitalocean. They have very cheap machines you can setup to do just about anything, and they have a wealth of good help documentation.

Comment: @hwjp Flask-SocketIO supports two transports, WebSocket and long-polling. I think long-polling should work just fine on pythonanywhere.